# BOBJ Webi Prompt with a specific subset of values

Tags: business-objects

I'm creating a webi report and have a few prompts defined at the query (not universe) level.  Unfortunately, the prompts return a butt load of values due to the design of the table.  What I'd like to do is restrict the list of values presented to the user based on a set of criteria.  Is there any way to do this in the query?  I'd like to avoid creating a specific prompt in the universe.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of BO are you on?  If on BI4, is the universe a unv or unx?

Comment: I think it's 3.1.  The version info pops up with 12.3.0

Comment: Yup, that's XI3.1 SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XI3, there's no way to do this without touching the universe.  In the universe, you can modify the LOV logic for a particular object -- click the "Properties" tab, then "Edit" under "Associate List of Values".  This will present a standard query panel; you can add conditions here, and the conditions will be applied whenever the LOV is displayed in WebI.  Note that this action will **only** affect the display of the LOV; it will *not* have any effect on how the SQL is constructed to generate the report.

Comment: Sometimes is just nice to know you can't do something.